# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at $.Result

Tags: android

i have get two response success and fail
My json success response

```
{
  "Status": 1,
  "Message": "records are available",
  "Result": {
    "id": 10135,
    "email": "payal@demo.in",
    "mobile": "8545324342",
    "first_name": "xyz1",
    "last_name": null,
    "vendor_type_id": 1,
    "status": "A",
    "subscription_name": "free",
    "profile_Image": null,
    "attempt_date": "2016-04-23T12:15:56.4815954"
  }
}
```

my json fail Response

```
 {"Status":0,"Message":"please enter correct email and password","Result":""}
```

Log message:
FailResponseretrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 75 path $.Result
i am using retrofit library
my model class

```
public class LoginBean {
    private String Status;
private String Message;

private ResultLogin Result;

public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    Message = message;
}

public ResultLogin getResult() {
    return Result;
}

public void setResult(ResultLogin result) {
    Result = result;
}

public class ResultLogin{

    private String  id;

    private String  email;

    private String  mobile;

    private String  first_name;

    private String  last_name;

    private String  vendor_type_id;

    private String  status;

    private String  subscription_name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getVendor_type_id() {
        return vendor_type_id;
    }

    public void setVendor_type_id(String vendor_type_id) {
        this.vendor_type_id = vendor_type_id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getSubscription_name() {
        return subscription_name;
    }

    public void setSubscription_name(String subscription_name) {
        this.subscription_name = subscription_name;
    }
}
```

}

my java code

How to parse json data inside json object data

```
RestClient.post().pharmacyLogin(etEmail.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString(), new Callback<LoginBean>() {
        @Override
        public void success(LoginBean loginBean, Response response) {
            //Log.d("Success", "Response" + response);
            try {
                // dialog.dismiss();
                Status = loginBean.getStatus();
                Message = loginBean.getMessage();
                String id = loginBean.getResult().getId();

                System.out.println("LoginResponse" + Status + "--" + Message + "--" + id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("Success", "FailResponse" + error);
            //AppConstants.showToastMessage(getApplication(), "Wrong Login Detail");
        }
    });
```

Comment: my Log cat Error Log:FailResponseretrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 57 path $.Result

Comment: can you paste your model class code

Comment: Post your model class in which you are trying to bind above response

Answer (score 1):

Look at your fail response.

```
 {"Status":0,"Message":"please enter correct email and password","Result":""}
```

See how Result is a string and not a JSON object?

It is a JSON object in your successful response.

You have an inconsistent model, and that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I the response there is something that is string , but you are trying to use that as object , thats why getting such error